# How to change the Link Status (up/down) at runtime in NS2?

Tags: dynamic, hyperlink, runtime, tcl, ns2

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386123/how-to-change-the-delay-of-a-link-in-ns2-simulation) and have a *similar* issue.

I wish to bring down a node when it reaches a certain Throughput. As mentioned in the post, the "`rtmodel-at`" method does not work. The answer to the post mentions changing delays of the link at runtime. I wish to know if the link status can be brought up/down at runtime using the technique mentioned in the answer. There is a method "`Link instproc down {} {}`" in `ns-2.35/tcl/lib/ns-link.tcl` for this purpose.

How do I call "`Link instproc down {} {}`" from the simulation script?

Comment: The core of it: `$myLink down`. The complex part is going to be the logic to get the handle of the link and to decide when to bring it down.

Comment: I am not aware of method to attach a `tcl` function to the flowmonitor. If you can tolerate some delay, you could use the FlowMonitor and check periodically the throughput of the link. An indirect way to check for the throughput would be to look at the queue occupancy.